# Showing Corner Radius on Segment Control inside a SizedBox in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

How to show the corner radius on a segment control. My segment control is inside a SizedBox which is again inside a Column with a container. I've tried wrapping CupertinoSegmentedControl and SizedBox inside a container with Boxdecoration but it didn't work. Attaching the code of the component.

**CustomSegmentControl**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 36,
            child: CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
              children: const {
                0: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12), child: Text('Segment 1',)),
                1: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12), child: Text('Segment 1',)),
                2: Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12), child: Text('Segment 1',)),
              },
              onValueChanged: (int value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedSegment = value;
                });
              },
              groupValue: selectedSegment,
              selectedColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
              unselectedColor: AppColors.backgroundShadingColor,
              borderColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is how i'm using this component -

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          const Center(
            child: CustomSegmentControl(),
          ),
          SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: LineChartSample(intensityValues: generateSampleData()))
        ]));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `CupertinoSegmentedControl` with `ClipRRect` and provide a `BorderRadius`:

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  child: CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
    // ...
  ),
)
```

The `CupertinoSegmentedControl` might not seem to be rounded yet because it has an internal padding by default. Remove or decrease the size of the padding:

```dart
CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  // ...
)
```